# Spark is duplicating work

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am facing a strange behaviour from Spark. Here's my code:

```
object MyJob {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sc = new SparkContext()
        val sqlContext = new hive.HiveContext(sc)

        val query = "<Some Hive Query>"
        val rawData = sqlContext.sql(query).cache()

        val aggregatedData = rawData.groupBy("group_key")
           .agg(
               max("col1").as("max"),
               min("col2").as("min")
           )

        val redisConfig =  new RedisConfig(new RedisEndpoint(sc.getConf))
        aggregatedData.foreachPartition {
            rows =>
               writePartitionToRedis(rows, redisConfig)
        }

       aggregatedData.write.parquet(s"/data/output.parquet")
    }
}
```

Against my intuition the spark scheduler yields two jobs for each data sink (Redis, HDFS/Parquet). The problem is the second job is also performing the hive query and doubling the work. I assumed both write operations would share the data from `aggregatedData` stage. Is something wrong or is it behaviour to be expected?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a fundamental concept of spark: Lazyness.

An RDD does not contain any data, all it is is a set of instructions that will be executed when you call an action (like writing data to disk/hdfs).  If you reuse an  RDD (or Dataframe), there's no stored data, just store instructions that will need to be evaluated everytime you call an action.

If you want to reuse data without needing to reevaluate an RDD, use `.cache()` or preferably `persist`.  Persisting an RDD allows you to store the result of a transformation so that the RDD doesn't need to be reevaluated in future iterations.

Comment: I'm caching but on a `rawData` step. And I still see some tasks for this step in the second job. How can I be sure that second job are getting its stage data from cache and not performing unnecessary work?

Comment: Yes you are cachine raw data, but not aggregatedData, so it needs to be re-evaluated on every iteration.  If you go into the spark application UI You will see all the data on what you'r application is doing.  Make sure that the data you cache fits in memory, if not try serializing or caching to disk (using `persist` and the appropriate storage level).